# Install newer version Eigen on Debian Jessie

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, libraries

I am trying to build the catkin workspace of ROS on Raspberry Pi (Debian Jessie 8) following this instruction https://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source

but encounter error

```
error: static assertion fail: Eigen support in pybind11 requires Eigen >= 3.2.7
```

Since the latest version of libeigen3-dev of Jessie Debian is 3.2.2-3 https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libdevel/libeigen3-dev

So I download the latest version of Eigen, unzip it and rename it to `eigen3`. Next I remove the old folder eigen3 in /usr/local/share and copied this newer version into it.

```
cd Downloads/
sudo cp -r eigen3 /usr/local/include    
cd /usr/local/include
sudo mkdir build
cd build
sudo cmake ..
sudo make install
```

And got this result.

[image]

But I have not solved the problem. Is there any way to verify that I have successfully installed the newer version of Eigen?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check for a few important files.  Specifically check for `find /usr -name Core -type f`.  Ensure that its parent directory is part of your build rules.

Comment: Hi, here the output run from my eigen3 file : `usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core` `usr/local/include/eigen3/build/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core` `usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core`. It seems to me that the last file is not in my buid directory right ?

Comment: @Stewart it seems to me that the `usr/include/eigen3`  have the same folders `Eigen` and `Unsupported` with my newly create. Do I have to replace those with my new version?

Comment: Right now, if you `#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>`, then you'll probably get your system's version (the old version that's incompatible).  You need to ensure you add `-I/usr/local/include` or `-I/usr/local/include/eigen3` to the compiler's command-line arguments so that your software can find those headers.